# Issues with PHP webservice with JSON from Android & SQLite

Tags: php, json, web-services

I'm making a webservice that takes a JSON flux from an Android app and insert it into a MySQL database.
I have no export errors with my app (which is running in a emulator in Android studio) and it seems that the issue is the webservice.
When I export the data from the app and I call the webservice I have nothing in my database.

Here is the webservice code

```
$hote='mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=gedimat';
$utilisateur='root';
$mot_passe='';
try {
  $connexion = new PDO($hote, $utilisateur, $mot_passe);
  $connexion->exec("set names utf8");
  return $connexion;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Erreur : '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
  echo 'N° : '.$e->getCode();
  return null;
}

// récupération du flux JSON
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);

// insertion ou mise à jour des données dans la table Vote
$res = $obj->Votes;

foreach($res as $unVote) {
  $requete = 'INSERT INTO vote(idVote, numTicket, idImage, note, dateVote) VALUES(:idVote, :numTicket,:idImage,:note,:dateVote)';
  $prep = $connexion->prepare($requete);
  $prep->bindValue(':idVote', $unVote->{'idVote'}, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $prep->bindValue(':numTicket',$unVote->{'numTicket'} , PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $prep->bindValue(':idImage', $unVote->{'idImage'}, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $prep->bindValue(':note', $unVote->{'note'}, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $prep->bindValue(':dateVote', $unVote->{'dateVote'}, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $ok =$prep->execute();
```

My json data looks like that

```
{"Votes":
    [
        {"idVote":1,
        "numTicket":"88888",
        "idImage":"2131165284",
        "note":"3",
        "dateVote":"2018-05-04"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you could help me with that it would be very appreciated.
If you need more info ask me

Comment: Is that ALL the data you show us or is there multiple occurances in the array?

Comment: There is multiple occurances in the array but there is only one there just to see if this works .

Comment: Ok amended my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks a lot dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's just a single array containing an object then the loop is unnecessary.

```
$res = $obj->Votes[0];  // $res is now the object

$requete = 'INSERT INTO vote
                            (idVote, numTicket, idImage, note, dateVote) 
                    VALUES (:idVote, :numTicket, :idImage, :note, :dateVote)';
$prep = $connexion->prepare($requete);

$prep->bindValue(':idVote', $res->idVote, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$prep->bindValue(':numTicket',$res->numTicket, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prep->bindValue(':idImage', $res->idImage, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prep->bindValue(':note', $res->note, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prep->bindValue(':dateVote', $res->dateVote, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$ok = $prep->execute();
```

If there are potentially more than one object inside the array then this should work for 1 or many object inside that array.

```
// prep the query outside the loop
// this can be reused, so dont do it each time round the loop
// and save a lot of trips to and from the database server for
// unnecessary compiles of the same query
$requete = 'INSERT INTO vote
                        (idVote, numTicket, idImage, note, dateVote) 
                VALUES (:idVote, :numTicket,:idImage, :note, :dateVote)';

$prep = $connexion->prepare($requete);

foreach ($obj->Votes as $vote ) {

    $prep->bindValue(':idVote',     $vote->idVote, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $prep->bindValue(':numTicket',  $vote->numTicket, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $prep->bindValue(':idImage',    $vote->idImage, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $prep->bindValue(':note',       $vote->note, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $prep->bindValue(':dateVote',   $vote->dateVote, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $ok = $prep->execute();
}
```